# How to fix a gstreamer error

Tags: sound, 14.04, gstreamer, input, output

I upgraded to 14.04 and now gstreamer is not working. What I am trying to accomplish is to hear the audio input on my computer coming from a ham radio. This is the command that I am using: `gst-launch pulserc ! pulseink`. This is the error message that I am receiving:

ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "pulserc". I think that I may be missing some plugins. I have been trying to investigate and found this troubleshooting website.

[gstreamer.freedesktop.org](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/chapter-troubleshooting.html.)

In it, I found this information. First I downloaded `gstreamer-properties` with `sudo apt-get install gnome-media`. Then I typed `gstreamer-properties` and a configuration page came up. [image: gstreamer-properties]

With these configurations I clicked on "test" and was able to hear what was coming from the radio through the computer. But I am still coming up with the same problem when typing `gst-launch pulserc` ! `pulseink`. I found another clue- `pulseink` also gets a "no element" error message. Thank you again everyone for all of your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have spelled incorrectly in your question? or maybe you're spelling incorrectly in your command. You are missing 2 s ie., should be  pulse`s`rc & pulse`s`ink

`gst-launch pulsesrc ! pulsesink`